# How can I make a ComboBox non-editable and set default text value in .NET?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to have a `select-only` **ComboBox** that provides a **list of items** for the user to select from. Typing should be `disabled` in the `text` portion of the `ComboBox` control and i want to set also the default value.

Comment: Windows Form @M.Babcock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `DropDownStyle` property to `DropDownList`

```
this.comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

Comment: Thanks but i want to set default value

Comment: I didn't get that? Do you want to set that through designer? or you want to set this property after adding some values?

Comment: Hari i got it thanks for help i set default text value on the properties and i paste your code to my program it works ... THANKS

Comment: @mark.bendal.erica Don't forget to up vote and mark this as answer if it is an answer to your question and helped you.

Comment: @mark.bendal.erica You can set the DropDownStyle through the designer properties as well...

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer stated you can make it `select-only` by setting `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`, you can find other ComboBoxStyles here. Here i would like to include a new `ComboboxItem` to the `0th` index of the particular combobox and make it as the default value: consider the following code;

```
cboSample.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
ComboboxItem newItem = new ComboboxItem();
newItem.Text = "Select an item";
newItem.Value = 0;
cboSample.Items.Insert(0, newItem);
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Where `ComboboxItem` is a class which is defined as:

```
public class ComboboxItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }
```